# Getting undefined when trying to get form value in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, forms, mootools

I have an input form, nested within a div, defined like this:

```
<div class="login-input">
  <input type="text" name="userId">
</div>
```

I've added a button below, and inside the click event for that button, I have code like this:

```
        click: function(){
            var user = document.getElementsByName(inputTitle)[0].value;
            var myRequest = new Request({
                url: '/Context/servletName',
                method: 'post',
                data: {'user': user},
                onRequest: function(){
                    $('container').setStyle('cursor', 'progress');
                },
                onSuccess: function(responseText){
                    $('container').setStyle('cursor', 'auto');
                    window.location = responseText;
                },
                onFailure: function(){
                    $('container').setStyle('cursor', 'auto');
                }
            });
            myRequest.send();
        }
```

This works fine in all of the browsers I've tested so far (Chrome, FF, Safari) but in IE8, the following line of code is causing problems:

```
var user = document.getElementsByName(inputTitle)[0].value;
```

I verified in IE dev tools that inputTitle has a value of "userId".  The problem is that

```
document.getElementsByName(inputTitle)[0];
```

Is undefined.

I also did a little bit of playing around.  Adding this to watch returns what looks like a valid object:

```
// Returns valid object
document.getElementsByName(inputTitle);

// Returns null
document.getElementsByName(inputTitle).item(0);
document.getElementsByName(inputTitle).value;
```

As always, thanks in advance...

EDIT:  Proof I'm not crazy....
[image: Values from IE dev tools debugger]
[image: JS Error shown in debugger]

[image: IE version]

Comment: That's weird, for me getElementsByName('...')[x] works fine and returns the expected object, on IE 8. Try clearing your cache.

Comment: Thanks for all of the answers everyone!  I'll give it a try when I get back to my dev machine.

Comment: @Delta - I've attached screen shots from dev tools showing it isn't working.  I don't know whats up; but @Oskar's suggestion did work so I'm not complaining.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick test-case to prove that the code works - http://jsfiddle.net/DmmcE/ (tested on IE8).

Doing a:

```
var user = document.getElementsByName('userId')[0];
```

Returns `[object HTMLInputElement]`.

Which means, the `inputTitle` you're passing is not passing the correct thing.

That said, since you're using MooTools, why not doing it the MooTools way:

```
document.getElement('input[name=userId]').get('value');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/UZTK4/

Comment: Hey @Oskar, I'm marking this as the answer because your MooTools suggestion was correct.  I would have preferred to do it this way anyways; I just didn't think to read up on the getElement method - so thank you for that. That being said, the first line DOES NOT WORK.  See the screen shots I've attached and note that the variable being passed in has a value of 'userId'.

Comment: @knurdy, unfortunately no.  I just went with Oskar's approach.

Answer (score 1):

Have u tried with .innerHTML.

Hope it works!

Comment: Hey @Kyaw, I gave it a try but no luck.  Thanks for taking the time to post an answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using an `id` and `getElementById` instead. This should be more more reliable and quicker; anything that supports JavaScript should support `getElementById`.

A bit of googling suggests that IE and `getElementsByName` really don't get along that well. I generally use ID attributes to refer to specific elements and rarely work in raw JavaScript for DOM wrangling so I can't say what specifically is wrong.

Answer (score -4):

Try using JQuery to get the element instead:

```
$("input[@name='inputTitle']").click(
```

here is a good link with more information
http://jivebay.com/2007/05/30/handling-checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-select-options-in-jquery/